# Two random variable with the same variance and mean

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $Y\in L^{2}(\Omega,\Sigma,P)$ and let $E[Y^2|X]=X^2$ and $E[Y|X]=X$. Could we prove that $Y=X$ almost surely.

My partial answer:

By the definition of conditional expectation we have $E[Y^2]=\int_{\Omega} E[Y^2|X] dP=\int_{\Omega}X^2 dP=E[X^2]$ and $E[Y]=\int_{\Omega} E[Y|X] dP=\int_{\Omega}X dP=E[X]$. Hence, Var$(X)=$Var$(Y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$E((X-Y)^2) = E(X^2) + E(Y^2) - 2 E(XY) = 2E(X^2) -2 E(XY)$$
the last equality being for the things you already proved.
On the other hand
$$ E(XY) = E ( E(XY|X) ) = E (X E(Y|X) ) = E(X \cdot X) = E(X^2) $$
The second equality is due a property of conditional expectations (that is essential!). Finally the variables are equal in $L^2$ which implies that they are equal a.s.

Comment: is the identity $E(XY|X)=XE(Y|X)$ easy to prove?

Comment: Yes, try first with indicator functions of sets from $\sigma(X)$ then extend to any variable $\sigma(X)$-measurable

Answer (score 1):

Yes, try $var(X-Y)=E(E[(X-Y)^2|X])$